# Redirect text file changes to batch file output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, atmelstudio

I am using a build tool which only writes its output to a text file, and I would like to use that build tool on a build server. The tool is Atmel Studio, and I try to start a build [this](https://avrstudio5.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/build-atmelstudio-projects-from-command-line/) way.

While the build is running, it writes its result to a text file, then the process of the tool ends.

I would like to have the text file output written to stdout, i.e. I would like the same effect as if the tool would write to the commandline output instead of the text file, in order to see what is going on during the build.

Is there any kind of command on a batch file to achieve this? If not, is there a good alternative?

Comment: Try `/verbosity:diag` command line switch.

Comment: I get a popup with "Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : verbosity:diag." when I add that switch.

Comment: Googling the verbosity setting, I believe it just sets the detail of the messages which are written to the text file. Given the fact that the command which I have to run effectively just starts another thread, I believe whatever is being logged just cannot go to the current commandline's output. Or am I missing something?

Comment: One thing to add(if anybody reads regarding verbose here): To get the verbose output in such a build, the compiler option -v needs to be set in the misc compiler options (->project file), this is not possible with a commandline switch.